# Solving numerically system with Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following system with Mathematica:

```
Poblacion = {
  {1900, 1.65},
  {1910, 1.75},
  {1920, 1.86},
  {1930, 2.07},
  {1940, 2.30},
  {1950, 2.53},
  {1960, 3.02},
  {1970, 3.70},
  {1980, 4.45},
  {1990, 5.30},
  {2000, 7.29}
  }

P[t_] := 1 / (-q (K t + C))^(1/q)

NSolve[{P[1900] == 1.65, P[1910] == 1.75, P[1920] == 1.86}, {K, q, C}]
```

But I can't get it working. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For this type of system `FindRoot` is more appropriate; however, why only using 3 points rather than making a fit using all the data ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks, I'd go further and suggest `FindFit[]`, even on the edited problem where only three points are taken.

Comment: How can i make a fit using all data? :S

Comment: `FindFit[]` can be used for that; look at the docs.

Comment: FindFit can't solve it either :\ I don't know what's wrong with the Jacobian

Comment: Do you have any idea about what the values of the parameters should be?

Comment: 1) `C` is a protected symbol; change to `CC` or something. 2) ["NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html) which you don't have. 3) The initial points are important; these yield a solution with `FindRoot`: `{{K, 0.001}, {q, 1.}, {CC, -2.1}}`; they are important for `FindFit`, too. 4) With `FindFit` put constraints on parameters so that the base of your exponential expression does not become negative.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider a different model. 
If you look at your data and try to make a guess the most obvious choice is an exponential; a double exponential looks even better :

```
ListLinePlot[{Log[#[[1]]], Log@Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ Poblacion]
```

[image: data]

If this looks fine then the fitting is straighforward :

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[{Log[#[[1]]], Log@Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ Poblacion,a + b t, {a, b}, t]
(* -206.05 + 27.1955 t *)
```

and in terms of the original data :

```
Show[ListPlot[Poblacion, PlotStyle -> Red], 
      Plot[Exp[Exp[nlm[Log[t]]]], {t, Poblacion[[1, 1]], Poblacion[[-1, 1]]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I get a resonable fit by adding a constant to your expression, and using Abs to ensure a real value returned..

```
P[t_] := 1 /(Abs[ -q  (K   t + CC)])^(1/q) + p0
ff = FindFit[
        Poblacion, {P[t]}, {{q, -.28}, {CC, -100}, {K, .05}, {p0, 2}}, t]
```

(* {q -> -0.0614064, CC -> -55.0774, K -> 0.0365885, p0 -> 1.56496} *)

```
Show[Plot[P[t] /. ff, {t, 1900, 2000}, PlotRange -> {0, 8}], 
               ListPlot[Poblacion, PlotRange -> {0, 8}]]
```

[image]

This only works by getting darn close with the initial guesses.

Comment: Slightly different starting values work equally well to give a different solution: I tried `{{q, 0.0308}, {CC, -98.4}, {K, 0.0338}, {p0, Pi/2}}`, albeit still with convergence warnings. (These can be suppressed using `Method -> "Gradient"` or `NMinimize`, but it appears that this just hides the symptoms rather than solving the problem.) Clearly this fit is quite ill-conditioned and it does not appear possible to exactly reproduce the given points, so it's debatable to what extent this can be considered a well-posed problem.

Comment: exactly.  As often the case, if you set about trying to manually fit your model to the data  by choosing sensable parameters you will discover that the model equation is not a good form.

Comment: How can i fit the model without the initial point?

Comment: @Trollkemada the model does not fit properly even with initial points given--note that george2079 had to change it to reproduce the data somewhat reasonably, and the parameters are still not well determined. I recommend that you revise your model or otherwise reconsider what you are doing (and then update your question), because not much progress is going to be made if people have to guess what you really want.

Comment: I have to find the best fit of that model to that data. I cannot change the model.